# AzureAD thinks a user exists when they don't

Tags: azure-powershell

This is using the latest Powershell and Azure modules. The user was deleted. My question is why can't I recreate them?

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName 

"bella.daniel@demo.co.uk"
Get-MsolUser : User Not Found.  User: bella.daniel@demo.co.uk.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "bella.daniel@demo.co.uk"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Get-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Admini
   stration.Automation.GetUser

PS C:\Users\Administrator> new-msoluser -DisplayName Daniel -UserPrincipalName bella.daniel@demo.co.uk -UsageLocati
on NO -BlockCredential $false -ImmutableId DANIELB620
new-msoluser : Unable to add this user because a user with the user principal name already exists.
At line:1 char:1
+ new-msoluser -DisplayName Daniel -UserPrincipalName bella.daniel@demo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [New-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UniquenessValidationException,Microsoft.Onlin
   e.Administration.Automation.NewUser
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah....so AAD doesn't fully delete users.
By running 
`Get-MsolUser –ReturnDeletedUsers -All | Remove-MsolUser –RemoveFromRecycleBin –Force`
I was able to clear them all out and "re-use" the UPN